# Add users in DNN Users Table

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to add a user in DNN Users table but I am not using DNN software. I am working with MVC project, so I added all the reference files.

My code is below:

```
DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo objUser = new 
DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo();

//objUser.AffiliateID = Null.NullInteger;

objUser.Email = "hfsdh@gmail.com";
objUser.FirstName = "Test";
objUser.IsSuperUser = false;

//I bet you will not create SuperUsers in bulk ;)

objUser.LastName = "Test1";
// objUser.PortalID = 0;    
objUser.Username = "Test";

objUser.DisplayName = "Test" + " " + "Test1";

//Usually here FirstName+LastName

objUser.Membership.Password = "121";
objUser.Membership.Approved = true;
objUser.Membership.Email = "hfsdh@gmail.com";
objUser.Membership.Username = "Test";
objUser.Membership.PasswordQuestion = "121";

//objUser.Profile.Telephone =Convert.ToString(phone);

objUser.Profile.FirstName = fname;
objUser.Profile.LastName = lname;
objUser.Membership.UpdatePassword = false;

string vSrav = "";

DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserCreateStatus objCreateStatus =
DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.CreateUser(ref objUser);
```

I receive an error like this:

> t DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.CreateUser(UserInfo& user) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\DNN_Platform_911_Public\Compile\DNN.Platform\DNN Platform\Library\Entities\Users\UserController.cs:line 913 at PPRO.WebApp.Areas.ProcurementPro.Controllers.ProUserManagementController.InsertUserData(String fname, String lname, String email, String phone, String uname, String pwd, String terms, String privacy) in E:\PPRO\PPRO\PPRO.WebApp\Areas\ProcurementPro\Controllers\ProUserManagementController.cs:line 176

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an "Object Reference not set" exception?  You may need to new-up the UserMembership object before trying to set attributes.

```
...

objUser.Membership =  new UserMembership(objUser) { 
    Password = "121";
    Approved = true;
    PasswordQuestion = "121"; 
};

...
```